# Merging two Datatables with different column names

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have two Datatables with differents columns name because they a filled from two different MySQL tables

- DataTable1 have `ID`, `Name`, `Brand`, `Genre` and `Creator`
- DataTable2 have `ID`, `Name`, `Brand`, `Type`and `EntryCreator`

I wanted to merge both of them so I can display both in `DataGridView1`. I did

`DataTable2.Columns(3).ColumnName = "Genre"
 DataTable2.Columns(4).ColumnName = "Creator"`

And then
 
    `DataTable1.Merge(DataTable2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add)
    BindingSource1.DataSource = DataTable1
    DataGridView1.Source = BindingSource1`

But on display, it only shows the data from `DataTable2`

Comment: Did you have set the PrimaryKey value for both tables to be the ID field?

Comment: I use a `MySqlAdapter to fill them. If it copies the PK from my MariaDB Database, I do, otherwise, I don't. (I don't declare the ID column as Primay Key)

Comment: Se let me understand. The ID field is the common key between the two tables meaning if a row with ID 1 appears in both tables then it refers to the same record for Name/Brand?

Comment: Not at all. It's two separate tables (Because they refer to differents "kind" of products) that share common points, but, they don't have the same data in them.

Comment: Can you simply change your query in the MySqlDataAdapter for the second table to have the same column's names of the first tables? IE _SELECT .... Type as Brand, EntryCreator as Creator ....._ In this way the two tables will have the same column's names

Comment: You're right, that's much more practical. However, the DataGridView still display only the DataTable2 values

Comment: What happens if you set _DataTable2.PrimaryKey = null; DataTable1.PrimaryKey=null;_ ?

Comment: I can't, Null isn't an argument in VB.net (It's taking it as if it was a variable). I tried vbNull and it gave me `Impossible to convert a 'VariantType' value in 'DataColumn()'`

Comment: Sorry I mean Nothing not null

Comment: Like the Karate Kid : "You're the best around". It worked ! You should post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is caused by the fact that Merge uses the PrimaryKey of the table to find an existing record to update and if it can't find it then add the new record. If this is the case then you should disable the PrimaryKey info retrieved when you have filled the table through the data adapter.

```
dataTable1.PrimaryKey = Nothing
dataTable2.PrimaryKey = Nothing
dataTable1.Merge(dataTable2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add)
....
```

Now Merge cannot find the matches and thus every record in dataTabl2 is added to the dataTable1. However I should warn you to keep an eye on the performances and correctness of other operations on this dataTable1.
Now there is no PrimaryKey set and this could be a source of problems in updating and deleting a row (if you have these operations of course)

Comment: Would it be helpful to set the `.PrimaryKey` to 2 columns. The OP said that they are different kinds of products. Perhaps ID and Genre/Type could provide uniqueness. Then a record could at least be updated or deleted.

Comment: It is possible, but we don't have enough info about the dataset and the constraints under which is formed